# Use AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer behind Proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, openstack, heat

We are currently setting up a private Cloud by using Heat in combination with Openstack. But we are struggling with the **"AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer"**-Resource when setting up a Loadbalancer with Heat because this Resource-Type has no User-Data and seems to use the **F17-x86_64-cfntools**-Image by default (can I change it?). Since we are behind a proxy and cfn-init starts trying to install some packages via yum (like haproxy) when Bootstrapping the Image we need to set a proxy before cfn-init starts. Is there any solution for this problem (except of patching the above Image while keeping its name unchanged)?

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

This question is answered here: https://answers.launchpad.net/heat/+question/237480  (no, you can't change it, but you can try using the quantum LBaaS instead)
And for people following along, the current version of the Heat source code that I've just looked at requires that the F20-x86_64-cfntools tools image be present.